# Where does iPad app store data?

Tags: ios, macos, itunes, ipa

I have an iPad app that downloads PDF and audio files.  I though these might be in the .ipa file (I used this thread [ipad - extract images from application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611402/ipad-extract-images-from-application)) but I didn't see anything there.

Is there some way to find where these might be stored on a Mac (after syncing)?

Comment: How the files are supposed to be in the IPA when the app downloads them from the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in many apps the media files will be downloaded to documents directory of app, which is inside the sandbox for the app. Simply telling when you instal a app OS will create a sand box, and all the data will be inside this sand box and only that particular app will have access to this data. So you will not be able to copy data.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: The documents folder is kept on the iPad?  Is there some app that can look into this folder from a Mac?

Comment: No, unless that app allow to share data with other app. like in photos app where from other app you can copy/import images.

Answer (score 1):

The IPA is an application only. Once it is installed on your iPad, it becomes a "package". It does contain the data within that package with some apps that store locally. There is no Apple supported way to get to this data directly. Think of it like this. The IPA is kind of like a blueprint for a program. Like a blueprint for a shelf, I could build the shelf but the books wouldn't be stored in the blueprint. Only the shelf. When you install the app, the iPad builds your "shelf".